# NLTK and PYTHON GRAMMAR

Tags: python, nltk, context-free-grammar

I already have python 2.7 and `nltk` installed on my system
please and please, how can I make my python program use the below cfg to be attaching part of speech to my sentences??

```
N -> 'ọnẹkẹlẹ'|'igbẹlẹ'|'ọma-ọnẹkẹlẹ' 
Pr -> 'Omi'|'uwẹ'|'awa'|'ama'|'oñwu'|'I'
Dart -> 'lẹ'
Adj -> 'kẹkẹ'|'nya'|'kpa' 
Adv -> 'ọgboolo'|'nyọnyọ'|'lile'
Ord -> 'ejodudu'|'ẹkeji'|'ẹkẹta'
Card -> 'ka'|'meji'|'mẹta' 
Quant -> 'wewe'|'gwẹẹ'|'Uchẹkibọ'|'uchẹkibọ'
Dem -> 'dẹi'|'i'|'lẹi'
Poss -> 'mi'|'wa'|'wẹ'|'ñw'|'ma'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this sample code from the [NLTK book, chapter 8](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html#chap-parse).

```
import nltk

grammar1 = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
VP -> V NP | V NP PP
PP -> P NP
V -> "saw" | "ate" | "walked"
NP -> "John" | "Mary" | "Bob" | Det N | Det N PP
Det -> "a" | "an" | "the" | "my"
N -> "man" | "dog" | "cat" | "telescope" | "park"
P -> "in" | "on" | "by" | "with"
""")

sent = "Mary saw Bob".split()
rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar1)
for tree in rd_parser.parse(sent):
    print(tree)
```

output:

`(S (NP Mary) (VP (V saw) (NP Bob)))`